Position of "aussi" when using question inversion
I would like to translate "Is the house small as well?" in the sense of "these other objects are small, what about the house?" (as opposed to further describing the house, e.g. "the house is expensive, ugly, and poorly maintained, what about small?"), but using a question inversion.
Honestly, I can't find a good place for the word "aussi", and the only phrasing that doesn't seem to violate my L2 brain's idea of where the word should go feels clunky:

La maison est-elle petite, elle aussi ? 
Est-elle petite, la maison aussi?

I think if I were trying to convey this orally, I would just say "La maison, est-ce qu'elle est petite, elle aussi ?", which also feels pretty long. Can someone help me with some ways to express this correctly using question inversion?

Both of your guesses convey the idea although the first one, depending on the context, might be understood to only mean there is another small house (or more):

La maison est-elle petite, elle aussi ?
Est-elle petite, la maison aussi ?

To make clear what aussi refers to, I would recommend to explicitly tell it, e.g.:

Leur maison est-elle petite, aussi, comme leur voiture ?

Orally, you have many choices :

La maison est petite, elle aussi ?
La maison est petite, aussi ?
La maison aussi, elle est petite ?
Elle est petite, la maison, aussi ?
Elle est petite, aussi, la maison ?
La maison, elle est petite, aussi ?
La maison, est-ce qu'elle est petite, elle aussi ?  (your suggestion)
Est-ce qu'elle est petite, la maison, aussi ?

and even more combinations...

Petite, belle marquise, votre maison est-elle, aussi ? (See this famous dialogue from Molière's Le Bourgeois gentilhomme.)


Si on doit faire de la prose: La maison aussi, elle est petite?.

@Frank Je prends. :-)

Petite, belle marquise, votre maison est-elle, aussi?

@FrançoisJurain Aussi !
